# xCode using variables

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I'm pretty new to Objective C in general...

I'm wondering how I can use a *variable in the view controller, and add it onto the web view URL. Bellow is a UIWebViewer, It loads "site.com/something.php"... Along with that I would like for it to addon to the URL "?uuid=(UUID Variable here)".

Sorry... I'm more used to PHP/Perl coding where you can just throw in "$uuid"...
Thanks,

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/something.php?uuid="];

    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```

Comment: You are creating a modified version of a string, so call `stringByAppendingString:` (or `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: Well first thing you need to learn is that `xcode` is an `IDE` and this question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well @Popeye if it comes to that, it has nothing to do with UIWebView either...!

Comment: @Shortland You are working with an NSString so read the class documentation on NSString. You might also want to read the section on string manipulation in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsstring_and_friends

Comment: @matt Thanks, I'll be sure to check into it, lots of great resources out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple you just need to create a property to assign whatever value you want to it

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; // Convention says that UUID should uuid

    // All we need to do now is add the uuid variable to the end of the string and we can do
    // that by using stringWithFormat:
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/something.php?uuid=%@", uuid]];

    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```

[Check the documentation of `NSString` and the class method `stringWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"http://www.site.com/something.php?=%@", UUID];
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
```

NSString's `stringWithFormat:` method allows you to build strings from literal strings and varaibles.  Variables are added to the literal string using format specifiers.  Most of the format specifiers are the same as all the other C-based languages, `%d` for integer types, `%f` for floating types, `%c` for char, etc.

In the case of `Objective-C`, the `%@` is used as the place holder for objects that respond to the `description` selector, which returns a string.  (In the case of an NSString, it just returns the string itself, but you'll notice that you can put lots of other types of objects in here too... in fact, every object that inherits from `NSObject` has a default `description` method).

Comment: Of what?  Are you running this in a simulator or on an actual device?